# IndexError: pop index out of range (python) 3

Tags: python, range

```
arrows=[]
badtimer=100
badtimer1=0
badguys=[[640,100]]
healthvalue=196

index=1

for badguy in badguys:
    if badguy[0]<-64:
        badguys.pop(index)
    badguy[0]-=7
    index+=1
for badguy in badguys:
    screen.blit(badguyimg, badguy)
# 6.3.1 - Attack castle
    badrect=pygame.Rect(badguyimg.get_rect())
    badrect.top=badguy[1]
    badrect.left=badguy[0]
    if badrect.left<64:
        healthvalue -= random.randint(5,20)
        badguys.pop(index)
```

Giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\Desktop\BB_Resources\game.py", line 80, in <module>
    badguys.pop(index)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Comment: the first loop increases `index` up to `len(badguys)` and you're reusing this variable in the second loop...

Answer (score 2):

Your initial problem is just what M. Fabre said: your loop index is valid through the first loop, but not the second.  To fix that, simply set **index = 0** before each loop (remember that Python starts indices at 0).

However, you have a deeper problem in your loops: changing **badguys** while you're iterating over the list will hurt you.  Try this test some time:

```
badguys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in badguys:
    print "Before:", i, badguys
    badguys.pop(i)
    print "After: ", i, badguys
```

This is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for what you're code does.  You need to change your work to keep the original list intact while you run through it.  Believe me, your program doesn't have enough hit points to take an "index out of range" critical hit.  :-)

I infer that the logic is something like this:

1. Remove any bad guy that ran past the castle (position < -64).
2. For any bad guy that just reached the castle, do 5-20 HP damage and remove that bad guy.

I suggest two passes for this: one to do damage (using **left** as your expression for the lateral position)

```
if abs(left) <= 64:
    # do damage
    healthvalue -= random.randint(5,20)
    # mark for deletion
    left = -999
```

... and a second to make a new list of bad guys.  Go through the list again, keeping only the ones still on the playing field:

```
badguys = [badguy if badguy.left > -64 for badguy in badguys]
```

Does that get you out of trouble for now?

Comment: I'm still confused, where should I add the passes. (I'm a new programmer so I don't really know what i am doing :P) Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Your replace your current logic with those passes.  This requires a little reorganization of your flowchart (or whatever pre-code planning tool you use).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this line:

```
index+=1
```

and it should work

Comment: Please take a look at @Prune’s answer from three years ago. It effectively identifies a similar issue. But it doesn’t _just_ explain _what_ to do, but also _why_ —and then continues on to identify other issues with the code. Remember that we’re here to provide an educational resource for future readers, so the explanation is often critical.